# VBA Excel Highlighting cells based on cell input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA script to highlight a particular range of cells when a user inputs any value in the cell. For example my cell range will be a1:a5, if a user enters any value in any cells within the range, cells a1 till a5 will be highlighted in the desired color. I'm a new user with VBA and after searching for a while found the below code that might be useful. Looking for advice. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Highlight_Condition(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.EnableEvents = False
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1

If .Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
    Debug.Print "Checking Row: " & i
    .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
Next i
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Edit: Trying to edit the code given by teylyn to be able to remove highlight from cells if cell value is removed however I can't seem to find the solution. (The original code will highlight the cells when there is input in cells however if you remove the cell value the highlight remains there.)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A12:F12")) Is Nothing Then

    With Range("A12:F12").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("A12:F12").Value) = True Then
       With Range("A12:F12").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65536
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Why are you using VBA instead of conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you describe, i.e. set a fill color for range A1 to A5 when any cell in that range is edited.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then

    With Range("A1:A5").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If
End Sub
```

This code needs to be put in the sheet module.

Edit: If you want the highlight to disappear if none of the five cells have a value, then you can try out this variant:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim valCount As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
' a cell in Range A1 to A5 has been edited
' we don't know if that edit was adding or deleting a cell, so ...
' ... we count how many cells in that range contain values

valCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A5"))

    If valCount > 0 Then
    ' the range has values, so highlight
        With Range("A1:A5").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
    ' the range has no values, so remove the highlight
        With Range("A1:A5").Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been testing the code and I noticed that after you input a value and the cells get highlighted, if the value is removed the cells remain highlighted. Is it possible to add a type of validation on those cells where the cell highlight will be removed once the cells have no longer a value?

Comment: @pnuts I'm trying to avoid conditional formatting and inbuilt excel functions.

Comment: "if a value is removed the cells remain highlighted". Yes, you never specified otherwise. When should the highlight disappear? Can you describe the rules in words?

Comment: I have posted a code variant that removes the highlight if none of the cells contain a value.

Comment: @TryStudent *" I'm trying to avoid conditional formatting and inbuilt excel functions. "* ... but why? I hope this is only as a learning exercise because 
a conditional formatting and excel formula solution is better than VBA solution for so many reason.

Comment: @Dan I get your point, but some Excel functionality like "filter by color" does not work when colors are set by conditional formats. There are different approaches to do this with either formulas or with VBA. Some would create a formula that returns text values like "red" or "green" and filter on that. Others prefer that the cells are actually colored red or green and want to filter by color. The beauty of Excel is that both these preferences can be built. One with CF, the other with VBA.

Comment: @teylyn yes but just because you can do it with VBA does not mean you should. You can just filter on the same conditions you're using for the formatting. I think filtering on colour is just going to make your sheet difficult for someone else to follow. Also VBA destroys your undo stack and adds hidden functionality that not always obvious if someone is trying to understand how the sheet works. I would rethink if you really need to use VBA here.

Comment: As I said above, I get your point. I'm actually in YOUR camp, but I understand that there are scenarios where the user does not want the most efficient solution but instead prefers a solution that supports the way they think, even if that is not the most elegant, time-saving approach. You ***can** vs you ***should***, well, in the end, it's about making the users' lives easier. If Excel needs two or even 30 seconds more to calculate the solution they "want" to use compared to the solution they "should" use, so be it. If they can understand the approach they can maintain it and keep it alive.

Comment: @pnuts I don't understand why you linked to that meta discussion. How does homework relate to this question or my answer? How does it relate to filter by color?